# RMI General understandment issues

Tags: java, rmi, stub

I wrote this little Program to illustrate my Problem (which doesn't make much sense on its own, but that does not matter):

```
public class Stuff extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IStuff{
  HashMap<Entry, String> map = new HashMap<Entry, String>();

  @Override
  public void exec(IStuff s) throws RemoteException{
    System.out.println(s.getEntryMap(this.e1));
    System.out.println(s.getEntryMap(this.e2));
    System.out.println(s.getEntryMap(this.e3));
  }
}
```

assuming there is a class Entry (also extending `UnicastRemoteObject`) and the HashMap is filled in the constructor.
There is also:

```
public class MyRegistry extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IMyRegistry{

  @Override
  public void register(IStuff s) throws RemoteException{
    s.exec(s);
  }
}
```

When i now call

```
MyRegistry r = new MyRegistry();
r.register(new Stuff());
```

it prints the contents of the map as expected.

If the `MyRegistry` instance runs on a Server, a different thing happens:

The server starts `MyRegistry`:

```
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
reg.rebind("Reg",new MyRegistry());
```

And the client uses it:

```
IMyRegistry reg = (IMyRegistry) Naming.lookup("Reg");
reg.register(new Stuff());
```

All it prints now is:

```
null
null
null
```

This makes sense, since the Registry gets a Remote Stub, and passes it to the `exec` method. The `exec` method itself calls `getEntryMap` *remotely* since it recieves a Stub of Stuff. Because of that, the `getEntryMap` method is called with a Stub of e1, e2 and e3. Of course the map has no entries of the Stubs, but of the actual objects. The `IEntry` instance recieved in `getEntryMap` is not an instance Entry.

**My Questions are now:**

- How can i get around this? I want `exec` to display the correct entries in any case. Is there a way to cast the stub into the actual object? Basic casting obviously does not work. It seems that somehow this should be possible, since `Stuff`, `map`, and the entries live on the client, and `exec` is executed on the client.
- Why doesn't the client notice that the Server returned a Stub which actually exists in my environment?
- Following that, why isnt every Entry stub in `getEntryMap() instanceof Entry`, or even the very same Object?

**Edit, Additional Information:**

The Actual `Stuff` Object created looks like this:

```
Stuff[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.1.68:60327](local),objID:[-1ff30562:13f0eb9f539:-7ff9, 219978949996152147]]]]
```

the stub in `exec` looks like that:

```
Proxy[IStuff,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.1.68:60327](remote),objID:[-1ff30562:13f0eb9f539:-7ff9, 219978949996152147]]]]]
```

Basically, it comes down to this:

- the actual object and the stub looks the same, exept that the stub is "wrapped" in the Proxy thing.
- Since `Stuff` is a `UnicastRemoteObject`, and the client keeps track of the exported objects anyway, it seems that it shouldnt be too hard to resolve the stub to the actual object.

Comment: Have You overriden the equals Method from Entry?

Comment: No, but does not make a difference. equals() and hashCode() are methods of Object. If i want to make them Remotely executable, i have to declare them in the Interface, with a `throws RemoteException` which is not possible

Comment: Ok. I was asking, because in the example You're storing it in a HashMap. Retrieving an object from it requires proper object identity resolution. That's my only guess, why would it return nulls.

Comment: That is part of the Problem. The stubs of the Entries are different Objects, with different hashes, than the actual Entries, so the HashMap returns null. I just dont see an elegant way to resolve the stubs to the actual objects.

Comment: Not enough information here, not even an adequate problem description. What's `Entry?` What type is `getEntryMap()?` `e1?` `e2?` `e3?`

Comment: @EJP as i said in the question: assuming there is a class Entry (also extending UnicastRemoteObject). `getEntryMap` takes an entry and does `return map.get(e)` `e1`,`e2` and `e3` are Entries

Comment: As I said in my comment, that's not sufficient information. The problem you're having results from the implementation or lack of it of the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in those classes.